# find intersection among days

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with a column containing code numbers and another with dates. I am trying to use dplyr and intersect to find the common elements among days.

Sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(A=c(2289,490,3940,1745,855,3954,2289,555,3940,667,855,3954,2289,490,12,1745,3000,3954,2289,490,3940,28,855,3954),B=as.Date(c("2019-08-01","2019-08-01","2019-08-01","2019-08-01","2019-08-01","2019-08-01","2019-08-02","2019-08-02","2019-08-02","2019-08-02","2019-08-02","2019-08-02","2019-08-03","2019-08-03","2019-08-03","2019-08-03","2019-08-03","2019-08-03","2019-08-04","2019-08-04","2019-08-04","2019-08-04","2019-08-04","2019-08-04")))
```

I am trying something like this:

```
df %>% group_by(B) %>% intersect(A)
```

The expected output are the codes that are common in each single day. For instance 2289 is the expecte value but 28 is not.

I wonder whether I can use intersect in this case.

Appreciate any help

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way -

```
df %>% 
  # filter(!duplicated(.)) %>% # add this if there can be duplicates
  count(A) %>% 
  filter(n == n_distinct(df$B))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
      A     n
  <dbl> <int>
1  2289     4
2  3954     4
```

---

A base R solution if you prefer `intersect` although I guess above method would be faster if number of groups is high -

```
Reduce(intersect, split(df$A, df$B))

[1] 2289 3954
```

Comment: Why not drop the `df$`?

Comment: @camille `B` gets dropped after `count(A)`.

Comment: Oh right. So couldn't you use `group_by` + `mutate` instead of `count`? Then you don't lose the other column

Comment: @camille I thought of that but I find above code more succinct and I don't see any problem with using `df$B`, is there?

Comment: In this case, I suppose not. In a more complicated case where you're checking `n_distinct` from something higher up in the pipe, you might run into trouble. It sticks out since it doesn't follow the normal tidyeval syntax, so I was mostly just curious as to why you approached it this way

Comment: @camille I does stick out but I disagree that it would run into problems. It is the same as using some external vector (that is not a part of `df`) in a pipe. I mean, it wouldn't look as "odd" if I defined `dates <- unique(df$B)` and used `n == length(dates)`.

Comment: Hi, code worked for me, Thank you. However I wonder if I could use intersect...I like set operations....

Comment: hi, the second didn´t work: Warning messages:
1: Length of logical index must be 1 or 6, not 0

Answer (score 1):

As a side note - you can do in `base` R:

```
sort(unique(df$A))[rowMeans(table(df)) == 1]

#2289 3954
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

`df %>% group_by(A) %>% summarize(if_all = length(intersect(B, unique(df$B))) == length(unique(df$B)))`

which uses `intersect`.